# Is the wording in "better even" interchanged grammatically?

Tags: grammar

Noisy neighbor, Dusan speaks to Paul:

> Paul, if tonight noise disturbs you, just come upstairs, talk to me.
>   Don't make big show like last time, yelling like crazy man. We're
>   neighbors. Neighbors are friends. **What's better even**, come to the
>   party.

Is the wording in "better even" interchanged grammatically?

I find these line in Downsizing 2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire paragraph, or rather, the dialog seemed like it was spoken by someone who isn't fluent in English, or maybe portrayed that way. Having said so, the paragraph has multiple grammatical errors. Deliberately or not, the writer wanted to convey something, by making it clear, in spite of having errors. This was done by making obvious errors, grammar errors and so on.

But actual idiomatic expression is, as you pointed out, "***even better***".

The writer must've done this purposefully. However, the meaning remains the same.